# Using reflection in C++ for LINQ

Tags: c++, linq

I am working on a small database project using C++ and [LINQ for C++](https://cpplinq.codeplex.com/).

I know reflection doesn't come with C++ by default, but I am confused how I can write a "query" and pass that in to the application at runtime.

Comment: have you seen this project is no longer maintened? - last commit was over 1.5 year ago. btw. read on `std::cin` for reading input from users.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string.
Your SQL query can simply be a string that you pass to the SqlCommand.